# Change default locale date d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

**I want to change the language to spanish in d3 dates.**

to do this in D3 v3 you can use

```
var format = {
  "decimal": ".",
  "thousands": "",
  "days": ["Domingo", "Lunes", .....]}

  var localeFormatter = d3.locale(format)
```

but now in D3 v4 d3.locale is gone.   and

```
d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(format)
```

seems to do nothing i dont know if is a bug or what.

I dont want to format the time like this link [D3 time-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#d3-time-format). 
i want the language to change.

i have tried

```
d3.local(format)
d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(format)
d3.timeFormatLocale(format)
```

¿Can some one help me on this?...

Answer (score 1):

In D3 v4, you should use 
    `d3.formatDefaultLocale(format)`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to do:

```
d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale(format);
```

*Before* you declare your scales, else D3 will take English as default.